# Maven Issue: changes to dependency version not passed to dependent project

Tags: maven

I'm using Maven 3.8.1 came bundle with IntelliJ IDEA for my project right now and I came across this issue when I try to change version of one of my dependencies.

The project itself contain multiple modules, in which one of the module, for example, snowy-plugin-biz-api depends on snowy-common like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>vip.xiaonuo</groupId>
        <artifactId>snowy-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I can add or remove dependencies from snowy-common and it will be reflected on snowy-plugin-biz-api, no problem.

The issue occurs when I try to change the version of dependency in snowy-common.

For example, if i change the Lombok version to 1.18.28 in snowy-common, maven will recognize that.
[image]

But when I check the Lombok version in snowy-plugin-biz-api, it's a bit different.

[image]

I tried maven clean and install but it just stayed the same.

The real problem I ran into is not about Lombok per se, this is just a demonstration.

Does anyone knows why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: clean/install does not change anything about the versions you have defined in your project. The lombok version (newer one) is comming through the spring boot version (unfortunately you have not written that which you are using)... I assume you are using spring boot as a bom (dependencyManagement import) and defining the your `snowy-common` is given as dependency... it would be helpful to have the full pom files of your project as well as of your `snowy-common`... etc.